# TypeError: can't pickle cv2.CLAHE objects

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, opencv, python

I am trying to run the code on github(https://github.com/AayushKrChaudhary/RITnet)

I did not get the semantic segmentation dataset of OpenEDS, so I tried to download the png image from the Internet and put it in `Semantic_Segmentation_Dataset\test\` to run the test program.

That code gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 59, in <module>
    for i, batchdata in tqdm(enumerate(testloader),total=len(testloader)):
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 291, in __iter__
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 737, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle cv2.CLAHE objects

(Machine_Learning) C:\Users\b0743\Downloads\RITnet-master\RITnet-master>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\b0743\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Machine_Learning\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

and my environment is:

```
# Name                    Version                               
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             
cudnn                     7.6.5                         
keras-applications        1.0.8                    
keras-base                2.3.1                   
keras-gpu                 2.3.1                      
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                                              
matplotlib                3.3.1                         
matplotlib-base           3.3.1                     
numpy                     1.19.1           
numpy-base                1.19.1                            
opencv                    3.3.1                                   
pillow                    7.2.0                                    
python                    3.6.10                            
pytorch                   1.6.0                                   
scikit-learn              0.23.2          
scipy                     1.5.2                                               
torchsummary              1.5.1                  
torchvision               0.7.0                   
tqdm                      4.48.2
```

I don’t know if this is a stupid question, but I hope someone can try to answer it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just got into the dataset python file and commented all the parts that require opencv.
Turns out it works but you wont get that sweet clahe and the other stuff but it works.
if you don't need the dataset thing just make a tensor out of the 640 by 400 image and put it in a empty array and put that array in an array until you have a 4d tensor and pass it in the dnn , and then put the output through the get predictions function and viola you have a array of eye features.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error and found that moving the line below from **init** to **getitem** solved the issue.

self.clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1.5, tileGridSize=(8,8))